# String search in UNIX

Tags: shell, unix

I have a xml file that has contents similar to below:

```
<tag>
    <sub>...</sub>
    <msg>....</msg>
</tag>
<tag>
    <sub>...</sub>
</tag>
<tag>
    <sub>...</sub>
    <msg>....</msg>
</tag>
<tag>
    <sub>...</sub>
</tag>
<tag>
    <sub>...</sub>
    <msg>....</msg>
</tag>
<tag>
    <sub>...</sub>
</tag>
```

I need a shell script that skims through the entire xml file and perform a search within each `<tag>...</tag>`. Within each `<tag>` if `<msg>` is present perform action 1 and if `<msg>` is not present perform action 2. How to do this?

Comment: I recommend you to use xmlstarlet and extract the data using xpath expression. Shell can do the rest.

Comment: What's action 1 and 2?

Comment: Do you have `xmllint` ?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a job for [XSLT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xslt)

Given this test.xml:

```
<document>
<tag n="1">
    <sub>...</sub>
    <msg>....</msg>
</tag>
<tag n="2">
    <sub>...</sub>
</tag>
<tag n="3">
    <sub>...</sub>
    <msg>....</msg>
</tag>
<tag n="4">
    <sub>...</sub>
</tag>
<tag n="5">
    <sub>...</sub>
    <msg>....</msg>
</tag>
<tag n="6">
    <sub>...</sub>
</tag>
</document>
```

Here's an example of a couple of xpath expressions

- "tag" tags that have a "msg" child

  ```
  $ xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//tag[msg]/@n' test.xml 
  1
  3
  5
  ```
- "tag" tags that do not have a "msg" child

  ```
  $ xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//tag[not(msg)]/@n' test.xml 
  2
  4
  6
  ```

Answer (score 0):

```
cat tagfile|awk 'BEGIN{ORS=" ";} {print;}'|sed 's@</tag>@&\n@g'>tempfile

while read line
do
echo $line|grep -i "<msg>">/dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ] then
Action1
else
Action2
fi
done<tempfile
```